# Abrir explorador de Archivos en genexus desde código html

Tags: genexus

Estaba tratando de abrir el explorador de archivo en genexus para importar un archivo xlsx. He visto que se puede incrustar código HTML para abrir el explorador de archivos.
El siguiente código sirve para abrir el explorador de archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código está dentro de un evento de botón.

El problema es que cuando ejecuta este código me redirige a la siguiente página. Como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo ideal sería que cuando yo presione el botón para importar un archivo me abra directamente una ventana para explorar los archivos.

Answer (score 1):

lo mejor sería que utilices el user control FileUpload

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30574,File+Upload+control

Saludos

Comment: Gracias! voy a probarlo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar una variable del tipo [Blob](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6704,Blob%20data%20type) en pantalla y el siguiente código en un evento
de un botón Importar por ejemplo:

```
Event 'Importar'
    &File.Source = &Blob //&File de Tipo File
    &Path = &File.GetURI() //Path de tipo VarChar
   
    If &Path.IsEmpty()
        Msg('Debe completar archivo')
        &Archivo.SetFocus()
    Else
        &ExcelDocument.Open(&Path) // &ExcelDocument de tipo ExcelDocument
                
        If &ExcelDocument.ErrCode <> 0
            MSG(&ExcelDocument.ErrCode.ToString().Trim() + ' - ' + &ExcelDocument.ErrDescription.Trim())
        Else //Recorres el archivo Excel
            &Fila = 1

            Do while not &ExcelDocument.Cells(&Fila,1).Text.IsEmpty()   
                MSG('Fila: ' + &Fila.ToString().Trim())
                &Fila += 1
            EndDo
                
            &ExcelDocument.Close()  
        EndIf
    EndIf
EndEvent
```

Esto asigna el contenido del archivo seleccionado a una variable [ExcelDocument](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2476,ExcelDocument%20data%20type) y lo deja disponible para manipularlo.

Y en el evento Start:

```
Event 'Start'
    &Blob.Display = 2
EndEvent
```

para que no se muestre el contenido del blob en pantalla.

Comment: Hola Guido! intenté realizar tu solución pero la propiedad Display no es admitida en el tipo de dato Blob. Estoy usando genexus 16

Comment: ¿Qué error/mensaje te da? ¿Ya tienes la variable en pantalla? Estoy usando GX 16 U2 y no me da ningún error. Revisa que tengas la variable &Blob en pantalla y el objeto guardado antes de agregar el &Blob.Display

Comment: Cree una variable desde la pestaña "Variable"... el error que me sale es de propiedad invalida error Src0216... Estoy utilizando Work With Plus y si agrego la variable desde ahí me dice que no se puede agregar una variable basado en el tipo blob... estoy utilizando GX 16U7

Comment: ¿La variable está basada en un dominio de tipo de dato Blob? Otra opción sería agregar un User Table(https://tinyurl.com/3spn3szr) y allí arrastrar una variable blob desde el web form.

Comment: Puede ser pero dejaría de estar sincronizado con los futuros cambios... Igualmente estoy probando con FileUpload